# Tracking foreign repo changes in a directory in git

Tags: git

I have synced code from my repository A locally, say we into `myProject` folder. Now I want to have code from foreign repository X under my project, say we under `myProject/libX` with these features:

1. I want to have all files under `libX` checked in repository A
2. I want to be able to regularly pull from repository X and merge into `libX`
3. I want to be able to make changes under `libX` folder
4. I don't have write access to repository X and don't want to push any changes I make in my project back to repository X

This seems to me like a usual scenario when I want to have external dependency in my project with being able to modify it locally only for my project. I was checking git submodules, but that doesn't work with the requirements above, namely that it pushes changes to the project X that I don't want/have access to.

Is there any best practice how to do this?

Comment: If I understand correctly, If you don't want to push to the submodule, either ask the maintainer of that project to revoke your rights, or just disable the push by pointing the origin it to an invalid path

Comment: Well there is no problem of pushing to the foreign repository "by accident", but with submodules I have to push submodule changes, otherwise they won't be persistent and when someone clones my repo, they won't get my modifications in the `libX`, no?

Answer (score 2):

The most no-fuss way of dealing with your "don't ever want to push" is,

```
git remote set-url --push origin .
```

after which all pushes will report "Everything up-to-date" since the local repo has exactly the same history as itself.

If you want it reporting an error, the ersatz-pushurl spelling I like is "You really didn't want to do that".

But if you want to *publish* your version of a project you don't have push access for, the simplest way to carry project-specific patches on a vendor history is to clone the vendor repo, carry the changes as a project branch and advertise that clone as the  `.gitmodules` upstream.

This makes work on your changes to the vendor upstream project perfectly ordinary, `git clone --recurse-submodules yourproject` works fine, your-submodule changes can be pushed back to the your-project-submodule upstream (the submodule repo's `origin` remote), everything works.

The only additional fillip is, to update your project's version of the submodule to the latest vendor code somebody has to fetch and merge from the (further-upstream) vendor repo

... but that's also perfectly ordinary: the way to fetch and merge from the vendor repo is, do it. `git remote add vendor u://r/l; git fetch vendor; git merge vendor/master`.  Or if you prefer rebase to merge, do that. Once you've done that, push the results to your submodule's `origin`, your project's version, all as usual.